# Mapping VirtualBox VMs to Vagrantfiles

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

How can I tell what Vagrantfile/directory is responsible for managing a given VM image in Virtualbox?  I think I might have deleted projects without doing a `vagrant destroy` first.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you are using a Unix based OS, vagrant 1.9.6 and VirtualBox 5, because there could have some differences in other conditions.

The `vagrant up` command will generates a `.vagrant/` folder inside the current path, there will be created some files with metadata which points to other path on your user `$HOME`, usually `~/.vagrant.d/`.

For instance, if you execute `vagrant up` inside the `~/example-vm/`:

- Vagrant will generate the following files inside the following path:

`~/example-vm/.vagrant/
  ├── machines
  │   └── default
  │       └── virtualbox
  │           ├── action_provision
  │           ├── action_set_name
  │           ├── creator_uid
  │           ├── id
  │           ├── index_uuid
  │           ├── private_key
  │           ├── synced_folders
  │           └── vagrant_cwd
  └── provisioners
      └── ansible
          └── inventory
            └── vagrant_ansible_inventory`

- Vagrant will generate the following files inside the path:

`~/.vagrant.d/boxes/example-vm/
   └── 0
        └── virtualbox
            ├── box-disk1.vmdk
            ├── box-disk2.vmdk
            ├── box.ovf
            ├── include
            │   └── _Vagrantfile
            ├── metadata.json
            └── Vagrantfile`

- Then vagrant will insert on the file `~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index` some metadata of your VM (`~/example-vm/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` and `index_uuid`)  in order to instruct where vagrant and your provider should interact to the VM which in this case would be the .vmdk and .ovf files.

You should just edit the files .vmdk and .ovf files.